# ¿Como hago un switch de dos botones flotantes que vienen de dos fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Actualmente tengo dos fragments que cada uno en sus respectivos layouts tienen un floating button que me redireccionan a otra actividad. ¿Como hago para traer el id de esos dos botones flotantes en un tercer fragment y hacer un switch con ellos?

Comment: Es necesario que sean los id's de los botones o puedes enviar otro valor que identifique de donde es invocada la actividad?

Comment: No necesariamente los id's pues es que tenia pensando hacerlo con switch para que se vea mas dinámico, pero si sabes con hacerlo de otra forma me seria útil también.

Comment: escribe el código java de uno de los fragment con sus fab

Answer (score 0):

Puedes enviar datos adicionales hacia el activiy mediante el método putExtra del intent.

Por ejemplo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent);
```

Y en el activity puedes recuperar el valor de la siguiente manera:

```
String sessionId= getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

Espero te sea útil.